# Getting user from DbContext after CreateAsync

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, blazor

I have a model called `AppUser` that inherits `IdentityUser` and I want to set some properties that exist only on `AppUser`. After creating the user via UserManager and getting the new `Id` I attempt to get the `AppUser` from `DbContext` however it is `null` and don't quite understand why.

How can I get the newly added `AppUser`?

```
...
var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
var appUser = _context.AppUsers.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==userId); // <--- This is null
```

Comment: But did you change all the Type parameters from IdentityUser to AppUser as well? E.g. `services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()` and the context class that is derived from `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>` should have IdentityUser replaced with `AppUser` accordingly.

Comment: I have found the problem. Because I use IdentityUser for AddIdentity and have AppUser inheriting from it, EF gives the table a Discriminator field which records which type the record was saved as. In this case as IdentityUser. Thus the AppUser context ignores those records